# Compare two list of list in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, list, append

I have two list

```
lst1=[['hey','jude' ,'fox'],['how','you','do']]
lst2=[['hey','paul'],['how','do']]
```

I want to compare each list in lst1 with each list in lst2. If they have common words greater than or equal to 1. Then I need to append the bigger list to a new list . If they have common words < 1 then I need to append both list to the same new list.
eg : `['hey', 'jude','fox']` is compared with `['hey','paul']` since they have common word hey which repeats once. I need to append the bigger list `['hey', 'jude','fox']` to a new list.

Comment: Please show the desired output.

Comment: What have you tried? See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your solution :

```
lst1=[['hey','jude' ,'fox'],['how','you','do']]
lst2=[['hey','paul'],['how','do']]
    new_list=[]
    
    for item in lst1:
        for item_1 in lst2:
            if isinstance(item_1,list):
                for sub_item in item_1:
                    if sub_item in item:
                        if len(sub_item)>=1:
                            if len(item)>len(item_1):
                                if item not in new_list:
                                    new_list.append(item)
                            elif len(item_1)>len(item):
                                if item_1 not in new_list:
                                    new_list.append(item_1)
    
    
                        if len(sub_item)<2:
                            if sub_item not in new_list:
                                new_list.append(sub_item)
                                new_list.append(item)
    
    
    
    print([j for i,j in enumerate(new_list) if j not in new_list[:i]])
```

P.S : You stated the question with confusion , what do you mean by
"words greater than or equal to 1." do you mean the length of words or matching of words ? I assumed the len of words.

Testing :

> with your lists:
>
> output:

```
[['hey', 'jude', 'fox'], ['how', 'you', 'do']]
```

when list one have less than 2 len letter in comman then :

```
lst1=[['hey','jude' ,'fox'],['how','you','do'],["wow"],["wllla","wlahi","aasma"],["h","i","j"]]
lst2=[['hey','paul'],['how','do'],["wllla"],["h"]]
```

output:

```
[['hey', 'jude', 'fox'], ['how', 'you', 'do'], ['wllla', 'wlahi', 'aasma'], ['h', 'i', 'j'], 'h']
```

when second list have largest common list words which match in both:

```
lst1=[['hey','jude' ,'fox'],['how','you','do'],["wow"],["wllla","wlahi","aasma"],["h","i","j"],["abc","def"]]
lst2=[['hey','paul'],['how','do'],["wllla"],["h"],["abc","def","ghi"]]
```

output:

```
[['hey', 'jude', 'fox'], ['how', 'you', 'do'], ['wllla', 'wlahi', 'aasma'], ['h', 'i', 'j'], 'h', ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']]
```

> if you want to avoid nesting break the logic out into a function to
> reduce the nesting.